# Laravel multiple withCount on the same relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship, laravel-5.3

I need to count the results from two different conditions, from the same relationship, but it's being returned as the same name.

```
Model::where('types_id', $specialism_id)
        ->withCount(['requests' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 1);
        }])
        ->withCount(['requests' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 2);
        }])
```

I can access the `withCount` using `$model->requests_count`, but because it's querying the same relationship, it appears to overwrite it:

```
select count(*) 
    from `requests` where `requests`.`id` = `model`.`id` 
    and `type` = '1') as `requests_count`, 
(select count(*) from `requests` where `requests`.`id` = `model`.`id` 
    and `type` = '2') as `requests_count`
```

How can I specify the name for multiple `withCount`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1**

Create two different relationships:

```
public function relationship1()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model')->where('type', 1);
}

public function relationship2()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model')->where('type', 2);
}
```

And use them:

```
Model::where('types_id', $specialism_id)->withCount(['relationship1', 'relationship2'])
```

**Option 2**

Create `withCount()` like method which will build property with custom names:

```
public function withCountCustom($relations, $customName)
{
    if (is_null($this->query->columns)) {
        $this->query->select([$this->query->from.'.*']);
    }
    $relations = is_array($relations) ? $relations : func_get_args();

    foreach ($this->parseWithRelations($relations) as $name => $constraints) {
        $segments = explode(' ', $name);
        unset($alias);
        if (count($segments) == 3 && Str::lower($segments[1]) == 'as') {
            list($name, $alias) = [$segments[0], $segments[2]];
        }
        $relation = $this->getHasRelationQuery($name);
        $query = $relation->getRelationCountQuery(
            $relation->getRelated()->newQuery(), $this
        );
        $query->callScope($constraints);
        $query->mergeModelDefinedRelationConstraints($relation->getQuery());
        $column = $customName; <---- Here you're overriding the property name.
        $this->selectSub($query->toBase(), $column);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

And use it:

```
Model::where('types_id', $specialism_id)
    ->withCountCustom(['requests' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', 1);
    }], 'typeOne')
    ->withCountCustom(['requests' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', 2);
    }], 'typeTwo')
```

Answer (score 19):

You can now do it like this

```
Model::where('types_id', $specialism_id)
    ->withCount(['requests as requests_1' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', 1);
    }, 'requests as requests_2' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', 2);
    }])
```

Comment: worked like a charm!! why these things are not there in documentation and from where you got to know it will work in this way?

Comment: I can't remember exactly on this one, but you can look at the underlining classes, see what methods are available and how things are implemented and that helps you write things in the most efficient way possible.